# Why additional subquery for minimum id gives 10x faster results?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

Ran into strange situation when additional subquery for limiting an id range gives 10 times faster results than same query in WHERE.

This query takes around 10s:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS count FROM
      items i
      INNER JOIN items_keywords ik ON ik.article_id = i.id AND ik.deleted = 0
      INNER JOIN category_keywords catk ON catk.keyword_id = ik.keyword_id
      INNER JOIN category cat ON cat.id = catk.category_id AND cat.customer_id = 968
      WHERE 
         i.deleted = 0 
         AND i.edited = 1 
         AND i.created >= '2018-12-18' 
         AND i.created <= '2018-12-20 23:59:59'
```

Explain:

[image]

If I add additional where clause setting the minimum ID, it takes up to 1 sec:

```
AND i.id > (SELECT MIN(id) FROM items WHERE created >= '2018-12-01')
```

Explain:

[image]

Tested it with setting i.id range with subquery (deleted i.created in main query and without minimum id clause) it took 10s and explain is same as in the first query except sub queries line and no created index in main query.

```
AND i.id IN (SELECT id FROM items WHERE created >= '2018-12-18' AND created <= '2018-12-20 23:59:59') #subquery takes 0,047s
```

So should I changes something in indexes or add that minimum id subquery to all my queries because it's big boost?
Waiting for any advice.

Some spec.:
Mysql: 5.6.4
items table: 22M rows
items_keywords: 120M rows
category_keywords: 70M rows

It's my first question here so don't blame me, but teach me.

ADD ON:
[Here is SHOW CREATE TABLE for these tables](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_xn1lKbVhxWyFx4zIkGV8YihpzsTRAiUjOEF7OPXeU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just to make sure, you have checked that both queries give the same results, right? (They should, assuming that item IDs are assigned in ascending order over time, and assuming that there is at least one item created between 2018-12-01 and 2018-12-17 inclusive. But it would be good to state that explicitly.)

Comment: Also, your EXPLAIN output (which you really should copy-paste here as text, if at all possible) mentions a bunch of indexes with names like "Index_2", "Index_3" and "Index_4". It might be useful if you could provide the definitions of those indexes.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes IDs are assigned in ascending order over time, and those queries give same results. Added link for SHOW CREATE TABLE's for further inspection, it has the information about those indexes. Copy pasting explain tables here looked ugly so made screen snippets.

Answer (score 0):

10x faster -- Sounds like the difference between the data being cached in the buffer_pool and not.  Did you time each query twice?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; there could be a lot of subtle things going on.

This index may trick it into using first:

```
INDEX(deleted, edited,  -- in either order
      created,          -- after those others
      id)               -- last
```

That index is "covering", thereby giving an extra boost.

Currently, the Optimizer decided to start with `cat.customer_id = 968`.

If `category_keywords` is a many:many mapping table, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for several performance tips.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` can be excessively slow.  `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` may be faster.

If you are going to move stuff into the subquery, move all the `i.` tests into it.  That way it will be essentially like `EXISTS`, and can use `PRIMARY KEY(id)` as the perfect index.  (No extra index needed.)

Comment: buffer_pool - Couldn't believe these results so ran those more than twice... Tested now, no matter how many times I run it it's about 10s.
Added SHOW CREATE TABLE's in main question (in google sheet - too much text to post here).

Comment: There is no such an index as you mentioned, it might help here, but still why it's 10x faster now.
Tried ruining it with EXISTS gave results in ~16s... (Sub query takes 0,047s by itself)
`WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM articles i2  WHERE i.id = i2.id  And i2.created>= '2018-12-18' AND i2.created <= '2018-12-20 23:59:59' AND i2.edited = 1 AND i2.deleted = 0 )`

Comment: @Simano - Will you be adding my index and timing it?  You proved my one guess at "why" to be wrong.

Comment: I was thinking to copy-replace the items_keywords table to have it reindexed maby some indexes failing or something. It's 34GB and really active table I can't stop it to be all re indexed. So maybe I'll add that index in copy-replace process.

Comment: @Simano - Performance of `category_keywords` can be improved by following the several tips in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @Simano - See pt-online-schema-change or gh-ost for "online" changes to big tables.